# d3.js change multiple domains in loop, then change attributes

Tags: d3.js

I have bar graph groups in four different "panel"s. I set xAxis domain all to 100 as default.

```
  var x = new Array(panel.length);
  var xAxis = new Array(panel.length);
  for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i] = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, 100]);
    xAxis[i] = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x[i])
      .ticks(10)
      .orient("top");
    panel[i].append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis[i]);
  }
```

By some mouse action, I want to change the x domain of four panels. So I did:

```
var fields = [100, 200, 300, 400];
for (var i=0; i<panel.length; i++) {
    x[i].domain([0, fields[i]]);
    panel[i].selectAll(".x.axis").call(xAxis[i]);
}
```

Then, when I change the width of bars (classed as "bar") that I've drawn in "panel"s,

```
for (var i=0; i<panel.length; i++) {
    panel[i].selectAll(".bar").transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        x[i](d.point);
    });
}
```

But it seems like not all of the x[] domains have changed. How can I change the domain of multiple axis at once in loop?

Answer (score 0):

You don't generally need to use a for loop with d3.js, it generally iterates through all items in a selection or through data you give it, but I think the problem you may be running into is related to your use of `i` which probably needs to be captured in a closure. You can do this by wrapping your function with a bind or an anonymous function but I think your function to width already gets the index as a second argument. I'd need to see what `.bar` was referencing or more of your code to know more.

Does something like this help?

```
for (var i=0; i<panel.length; i++) {
    panel[i].selectAll(".bar").transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("width", (function(xFunc) { 
        return function(d) { xFunc(d.point); }
    })(x[i]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" error at the second last line. I understand the iteration, but in my case, I need four areas (i.e., panel), in each of which, a separate dataset is called. So I thought I needed to make loop for the wrapper areas..

Comment: I used your example in other similar case, and it says Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function..

Comment: I fixed my syntax error. You're going to have to understand at least something about JavaScript and what's in your code to use d3.js. Obviously if x[i] isn't a function you can't treat it as such.